# What is the remainder when $6^{99} + 8^{99}$ is divided by $49$? How can we solve this using the Binomial Theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried it as $(7-1)^{99} + (7+1)^{99}$ divided by $49$. I am getting stuck after this. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have started rightly as

$$6^{99}=(7-1)^{99}\equiv(-1)^{99}+\binom{99}17\pmod{49}\equiv-1+99\cdot7$$

Similarly for $\displaystyle8^{99}=(7+1)^{99}\cdots\equiv1+99\cdot7$

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee so is the answer 14 then?

Comment: @Sharon, It should be $$2\cdot99\cdot7=2(98+1)7\equiv2\cdot1\cdot7\pmod{98}\equiv14\pmod{49}$$

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Expand each of $(7-1)^{99}$ and $(7+1)^{99}$ using the Binomial Theorem. Note which factors are divisible by $49 = 7^2$, and see what's left over.

Answer (score 2):

Try working mod $7$.

The rationale behind that is that then you are working with powers of $±1$, which is significantly easier than working with powers of $6$ and $8$. And in this case, this will actually give you the answer.

Comment: It becomes slightly more complicated because it is mod 49, not just 7.

Answer (score -1):

how about using **modular-exponentiation** ?
It's very simple and I think it could help you...

```
int b_power_of_n_mod_m(int b, int n, int m) {
    //convert n to binary and save in A array 
    int A[] = new int[20];
    int i = 0;
    // n must be positive
    while (n > 0) {
        A[i++] = n & 1;
        n = n >> 1;
    }
    int x = 1;
    int power = b % m;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (A[j] == 1) x = (x * power) % m;
        power = (power * power) % m;
    }
    return x;
}
```

just use it and you can see that it is very fast :)

Comment: While computers _can_ be an aid sometimes, this isn't primarily a programming site, and this problem has an answer that's easily within the realm of pencil-and-paper computation; there's just no need for this.

Comment: what ??? I didn't know that :|

Comment: but modular-exponentiation is not just for programming...google it!

Comment: I don't think brute modular exponentiation is very practical for pencil-and-paper computation. Further more, I would like to point out that all computations are natively done in binary format on computers, and there is no need to explicitly split up an int into 20 ints. It only slows down computations.